# Lambda doesn't recognize python dependency

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

For my lambda function I need this library: https://github.com/explosion/tokenizations (Listed under pytokenizations on PyPi)

I've installed it with `pip install --target ./package` , zipped it and brought it to lambda, but when I run my function (the exact same code works fine on my machine) I get the following error: `"Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'tokenizations'"`

EDIT: The actual error is  `"Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'tokenizations.tokenizations'"` Wouldn't the normal output be just one time `tokenizations`?

The other module I'm using through the /package folder is working just fine.

What could be possible causes for this?

Comment: Can you open the zip file and verify the tokenizations library is there, in the same folder as the other libraries that are working?

Comment: Yes, it's there